# Creating one line of best fit for multiple overlapping .gpx files

Tags: qgis

I am new at QGIS and am trying to create a map of ski trails. I mapped out all the trails but in some places I passed by the trail more than once. On the .gpx file it shows as two separate lines and am wondering if there is a way to merge the lines into one? I want to try and create a line of best fit of all the trips I have done.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Arcgis solution https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219997/how-to-get-average-line-of-2-nonparallel-lines/220340#220340

Answer (score 1):

It might be easiest to created a new line simply by manually digitizing over the linework for your .gpx file(s).  You could try using the "new shapefile layer" function to digitize.