# Combining polylines which share endpoints using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am working with a shapefile of streets which include links between two intersections represented as two polylines (depending on presence of a median, for instance). I would like to merge such parallel lines with overlapping end points into a single polyline in order to develop a consistent segment-level unit of observation.

I have tried using different tools in ArcGIS Desktop ("dissolve", "unsplit", "merge divided roads", "collapse dual lines to centerlines") and R (gLineMerge) based on other Q&As with similar sounding issues, but not of these tools/packages resolves the issue across the network.

Let's say the input network looks like the image below. The lines that are highlighted are the lines which are divided, but share common begin and end points.

[image]

What I would like is for to simplify the network so as to have these divided roads replaced by a single line, as illustrated by the handdrawn coloured lines below.

[image]

Any thoughts on what steps could I do in ArcGIS Desktop to automate such process?

The attributes of the lines include "from node" and "to node" columns, but I would like for the geometry to be averaged out ideally (as opposed to removing duplicates).

Comment: What do you mean by merge? Replace 2 lines that share start/end nodes by single (straight?) line? Perhaps show intended output.

Comment: @FelixIP Yes, replacing it with a single, straight line, or some averaged out version of it.

Comment: Intersect lines with themselves with Point as ouput then run Points to line

Comment: @BERA Thanks for that suggestion. I just tested it out on a small subset of the network, and the intersect feature creates as a multipoint layer, which isn't compatible with the "points to line" tool. My other concern with the approach is that since these lines typically intersect near the end points, for lines which include curves but are also divided, the points to line feature may not follow the curve. Any further thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: It is simple for short segments, that can be replaced by straight line, but in general I afraid it is long path https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219997/how-to-get-average-line-of-2-nonparallel-lines   , i.e. some coding needed.