# Creating polyline that represents Mean shoreline position from set of 4+ polyline positions for that year using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, line, interpolation, polyline-creation

I am looking at tracking shoreline positions across a few decades and in order to remove the noise of seasonal change I want to  create a mean shoreline position that represents several shorelines that I have tracked from satellite images. So I want to make a single polyline that represents the average of all of those for that year.

[image: image of polylines that I want to make and average from]

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219997/getting-average-line-of-two-non-parallel-lines-using-arcgis-desktop/220340#220340

Comment: Not sure this answers your question but are you aware of the free shoreline mapping software for arcmap called DSAS?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it (these are steps of a proposed process, without explicit instructions on how to perform each step):

- Firstly, make sure that the start and end points of each line are equivalent points (perhaps by drawing a line across the start/end and right angle and then clipping the lines to that same start/end).  This is only necessary if one of the lines protrudes beyond the other(s) so that they are not starting and/or ending at equivalent locations.
- Generate an equivalent series of points along each line using the 'Generate Points Along Lines' tool ( https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/generate-points-along-lines.htm ).  You should use the 'Percentage' Placement option to make sure that you end up with the same number of points along each line, but that they still fill the line (eg, create a point every 1% along the line to get 100 points along each line).  You can either run it once for each line, or if the lines are all in the same feature class, you can run it once for all lines, and then separate the results out into separate feature classes according to the original FID in the output points feature class.  But you need to end up with a separate feature class of points for each source line.
- Now you need to create a series of interpolated points that will become the vertices of the final (interpolated) line.  To do this, traverse each pair (or set if more than two source lines) of the series of points-along-lines simultaneously, and for each set of points (starting with the first point along each line) create (interpolate) the new point as having the mean/average coordinates of the source points.  Append the new (interpolated) point to a point feature class.  (You may want to use some formula other than mean/average - up to you).
- Then just create a line using the generated (interpolated) points as the vertices (eg, use Points to Line tool - in which case, in the previous step, you may want the interpolated points to have an index number in a field that you can feed to the Points to Line tool to have them ordered correctly).

NB:  I've not actually tried this.  So if you do try it, I'd be interested to hear about the results.

If you want more explicit instructions on any particular step, that may be worth asking in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried least cost path functionality.
First computed kernel density of **vertices**, saved to raster TOTAL:

[image]

Force future path inside "red" area using raster calculator:

```
dByD = 1-"TOTAL"/"TOTAL".maximum
COST = Exp(5*"dByD")
```

Picture below is vector representation of least cost path between points at the end of polylines. It fits my understanding of 'mean' line, i.e. it biased to the areas with higher line density:

[image]